# How to load an API dynamically by using button values in angular 6,7,9

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

```
**How to load an API dynamically by using button values in angular 6,7,9**
```

**i need to display the API as per the button Alphabetic Values so please help me to rectify the solutions**

```
app.component.html:
<p>brands-all will replace here !</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button value="%23">#</button></td>
    <td><button value="A">A</button></td>
    <td><button value="B">B</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<ul *ngFor = "let eachBrand of brandResponse?.brands.brands['B']">
  <li style="float:left; list-style-type: none;">
    <a href="{{eachBrand.url}}">{{eachBrand.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>


app.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-brands-all',
  templateUrl: './brands-all.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./brands-all.component.scss']
})
export class BrandsAllComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  brandResponse;
  searchparam = 'B';
  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.http.get("/api/landing?type=MERCHANDISE&prefix=" + this.searchparam)
      .subscribe((data) => this.displaydata(data));
  }
  displaydata(data) {this.brandResponse = data;}
}



**How to load an API dynamically by using button values in angular 6,7,9**
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make click event for every button like that

```
<td><button value="%23" (click)="handleClickBtn('%23')">#</button></td>
    <td><button value="A" (click)="handleClickBtn('A')">A</button></td>
    <td><button value="B" (click)="handleClickBtn('B')">B</button></td>
```

it your ts file

```
handleClickBtn(value){
   this.http.get("/api/landing?type=MERCHANDISE&prefix=" + value)
      .subscribe((data) => this.displaydata(data));

}
```